# Call operator in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have implemented a Matrix class that provides a call operator to access it's elements:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T* data;
public:
    // constructors, destructor, other functions...
    T& operator () (unsigned row, unsigned col) {
        return data[row*cols+col];
    }
}
```

In some application code I use the example like

```
Matrix<double> m;
m(0,0) = 3.14;
```

This gives the following compiler error:

```
type 'Matrix<double>' does not provide a call operator
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: `cols` or `col` ?

Comment: maybe you have some other Matrix template class definition?

Comment: [Cannot reprodiuce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/095727a54ad7d9c0).  Pleae provide a [mcve]